# Two fixed columns and a scrollable centre

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to have two side-columns which remain fixed while the column in the centre can be scrollable. While the column on the right remains fixed, the contents of my left column does not stick within its bounds. It's contents overflows, and it takes up the whole row. Because it is defined first, it appears behind the other containers. How do I get it to stick to the left and not overflow?

```
<div class = "row">
        <div class=" container col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm2" id="left-sidebar">
                        <div class="panel panel-default affix">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Skill-Set</div>
                    <div class="panel-body" align="justify">

                    </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="nav ">

                </div>
                <!--/.well -->
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="container col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2>Who am I?</h2>
                <p align="justify">Stuff
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div class=" container col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm2" id="right-sidebar">
            <div class="panel panel-default pull-right affix">
                    Stuff
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to be using in your CSS is the property

```
overflow-y: auto / hidden
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vw0h7y40/1/) to show you how to achieve the 3 column design with 2 fixed and 1 scrolling simply with the use of CSS.